# ES6 Javascript: Calling static methods from classes with arrow functions

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class, arrow-functions

While this works as intended

```
class ClassWithStaticMethod {

  static staticMethod() {
    return ('staticMethod');
  };

  static staticMethod2() {
    const yee = this.staticMethod();
    return 'staticMethod2 '+yee;
  };

}

console.log(ClassWithStaticMethod.staticMethod2());
//staticMethod2 staticMethod
```

This is,

i) have access to the staticMethod() with the class name, and

ii) this method can call another static method within the same class by using "**this**",

This doesn't work

```
class ClassWithStaticMethod {

  static staticMethod = () => {
    return ('staticMethod');
  };

  static staticMethod2 = () => {
    const yee = this.staticMethod;
    return 'staticMethod2 '+yee;
  };

}

console.log(ClassWithStaticMethod.staticMethod2());
//staticMethod2 undefined
```

In the sense, that I can still access to the staticMethod() method, but I am not able to access to the other method within the first method. I get undefined, and if I use

```
    const yee = this.staticMethod();
```

I get an error

> error TypeError: _this.staticMethod is not a function

Comment: That's one problem with arrow functions: they have generic scoping of `this`. (That's why we have to use `function()` if you want a better call stack). In the second method, `this` refers to the calling context: `window`.

Comment: @weirdpanda - That's not a problem with arrow functions.  It's how they're designed and what there purpose is!  If you want the regular method call behavior for `this`, then use a regular method call, not an arrow call.

Comment: @jfriend00, I am so sorry, my language was a little off there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Arrow functions inherit their `this` from the outer scope rather than their `this` depending on their calling context. Since `staticMethod2` tries to access `this.staticMethod`, that will only work if `this` refers to `ClassWithStaticMethod` - that is, if `staticMethod2` is a *standard function*, not an arrow function.

You also need to *invoke* `this.staticMethod()`. (`const yee = this.staticMethod;` will result in the `staticMethod` being coerced to a string, rather than being called)

Change those two issues, and it works as expected:

```js
class ClassWithStaticMethod {

  static staticMethod = () => {
    return ('staticMethod');
  };

  static staticMethod2 = function() {
    const yee = this.staticMethod();
    return 'staticMethod2 '+yee;
  };

}

console.log(ClassWithStaticMethod.staticMethod2());
```

Comment: Damn it, you beat me to it.

Comment: Thanks to both. So the real answer (once you understand the problem I mean) is that there is no method to "unbind" the This when using the arrow functions, is it?

Comment: @Gerard That's right, when you use an arrow function, `this` will always depend on the lexical location of the block the `this` is in, and nothing else it won't depend on how you invoke it.

Comment: @Gerard - Yeah, don't use an arrow function when you don't want `this` to work like arrow functions work.  That's how they are designed - that is their main purpose in life.  Use a regular function call if you want the regular behavior for `this`.  Or use `.bind()` or `.call()` with a regular function to override how `this` works for a specific function call.  Use the appropriate tools for the job.  This is not a problem with arrow functions.  This is how they were designed and you are apparently trying to use them for the wrong purpose.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes, understood :)

Answer (score 2):

That's one quirk with arrow functions when it comes to general use: they have generic scoping of `this`. (That's why we have to use `function()` if you want a better call stack). In the second method, `this` refers to the calling context: `window`.

As mentioned below in the comment, do not use the short-hand syntax for your convenience; there is a reason we have so many options.

To fix it, you can just use `function()` to define the second function; or `()` in the object case.

This, however, would work:

```
class ClassWithStaticMethod2 {

  static staticMethod = () => {
    return ('staticMethod');
  };

  static staticMethod2 = function() {
    console.log(this)
    const yee = this.staticMethod();
    return 'staticMethod2 '+yee;
  };

}
```

Check it out [here](http://jsbin.com/piyarohoqo/1/edit?js,console).

Comment: As I said above, this is not a "problem" with arrow functions.  It's how they are designed and is their main purpose in life.  Some people go a little nuts and try to use the shorter syntax everywhere, even where the main function of an arrow function is not the desired behavior.  That's just a wrong mode to be in.  One should use an arrow function when you want the `this` value to be lexical, not when you want it to be taken from object.method.  One has to use the appropriate tools for the appropriate job.  I'd suggest rewording your answer more along those lines.

Comment: There was a lovely piece of code I saw by Eran Hammer where he used `function` as opposed to `() => {}` and someone asked him the reason; his reason was exactly what you said. In another talk, I saw the reason to use `... = function()` was because of the stack trace as `() => {}` forms an annon function. I misworded the answer,  I will just correct it! O